# TableAdapter.Update() doesn't work

Tags: c#, dataset, sql-server-ce

I want to remove existing records from Database and add new data to Database. I used the following code. It is running correctly but when I see database through database viewer in Visual Studio, I can't see any update in Database.

```
Databases.MoodleOCDataSet quizDT = new Databases.MoodleOCDataSet();
Databases.MoodleOCDataSetTableAdapters.QuizTableAdapter tableAdaptor = new Databases.MoodleOCDataSetTableAdapters.QuizTableAdapter();            
tableAdaptor.Fill(new Databases.MoodleOCDataSet.QuizDataTable());

string[] quizList = GetServerQuizList();

quizDT.Quiz.Clear();

foreach(string quiz in quizList)
{
    Databases.MoodleOCDataSet.QuizRow row = quizDT.Quiz.NewQuizRow();
    row.course = 1;
    row.name = quiz;
    quizDT.Quiz.Rows.Add(row);
}

tableAdaptor.Update(quizDT.Quiz);
```

Comment: try to return something from update method stuch as int result = tableAdaptor.Update(quizDT.Quiz); and then check if (result > 0). If it is then, (which is 1) then it is true, otherwise your result will be false.

Comment: I tried and it returns value 5.

Comment: your query is basically updating 5 rows

Comment: it means 5 rows have been updated.

Comment: Yes I am adding five items to database. But I cant see them. It only contains previous values. Database is not cleared also.

Comment: Do you have two test database?

Comment: @MichaelBuen Sorry I didnt get what you say.

Comment: I mean, if you are testing on two database? Your code might be working but the data goes to the other database. Meaning, you are looking on the wrong database. Check the other database. Check your connection string if it is

Comment: @MichaelBuen no I dont have two databases. I only have single database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually this is not a issue with update command. Visual Studio keeps two databases. One in project folder and one in bin/debug folder. Database in bin/debug folder always update with Database in project folder. If you view Database through Visual Studio, it always shows the Database inside the project folder not other one inside bin/debug folder.

Comment: So I take it that you have two databases ;-)

Comment: Well sort of. I checked the connection string but it leads me to wrong database. Thing really happens is I didn't got your comment. I thought you were talking about two separate databases. But thanks for that comment.